# Fetch only works on refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js

I am trying the new Nuxt.js Fetch method. Initially, I thought everything was fine. But the data is only fetched and rendered when I refresh the page.
However, if the page is accesses through  $fetchState.error equals true and the data is never fetched.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<template>
  <main>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p v-if="$fetchState.pending">
          Fetching vehicles...
        </p>
        <p v-else-if="$fetchState.error">
          Error while fetching vehicles
        </p>
        <div
          v-for="(vehicle, index) in usedVehicles"
          v-else
          :key="index"
        >
          <nuxt-link :to="`cars/${vehicle.Id}`">
            {{ vehicle.Make }}
          </nuxt-link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button @click="$fetch">Refresh Data</button>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      usedVehicles: []
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      'https://random.com/api'
    )
    // `todos` has to be declared in data()
    this.usedVehicles = data.Vehicles
  },
  methods: {
    refresh() {
      this.$fetch()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: fetch may finish after mounted - therefore when you refresh - it may have that data cached. use asyncData if you wish to retain that data on the server render before first mount

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have figured out the issue may lay in the API i am using. I've tried coping the JSON and hosted it on another server. This seemed to help me. But why, I don't know.

Comment: feel free to upvote anyway - thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just answered a related question re: `fetch`

So in the lifecycle hooks,

The fetch is called (but only finishes after the page is mounted).
This means that when you refresh the page, the data should be cached on the client side (hence renders the `this.usedVehicles`).

If you want to ensure that the data is retrieved before the first mount, you can use `asyncData` and await the call - such that `usedVehicles` is set before the page is mounted.

example

```
<template>
  <main>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p v-if="$fetchState.pending">
          Fetching vehicles...
        </p>
        <p v-else-if="$fetchState.error">
          Error while fetching vehicles
        </p>
        <div
          v-for="(vehicle, index) in usedVehicles"
          v-else
          :key="index"
        >
          <nuxt-link :to="`cars/${vehicle.Id}`">
            {{ vehicle.Make }}
          </nuxt-link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button @click="$fetch">Refresh Data</button>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      usedVehicles: []
    }
  },
  async asyncData() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      'https://random.com/api'
    )

    return { usedVehicles: data.Vehicles }
  }
  async fetch() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      'https://random.com/api'
    )
    // `todos` has to be declared in data()
    this.usedVehicles = data.Vehicles
  },
  methods: {
    refresh() {
      this.$fetch()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This will mean that on each request, theres going to be some delay to retrieve that data - but it depends if that is your desired result.

[image: lifecyclehooks]